# Email a very large list of WordPress subscribers = fail (every single time)

Tags: wordpress, email, bulk-email

I have tried using a number of plugins to email my 40,000 registered users on my WordPress-powered site, to no avail. I have tried Subscribe2 (seems to send some, but I have no idea how many) as well as a few Newsletter plugins. I either run out of memory trying to add 40K entries to the mail queue, or I error out trying to add 40K emails in the BCC of the email being sent.

Is there anyone out there with a large subscriber-base that has found a successful solution? If so, please share.

Answer (score 2):

With a mailing list that size you may want to consider using services like [Constant Contact](http://www.constantcontact.com/) to handle your mailings. Sure, it's not free, but they can easily handle that kind of volume plus you get the benefit of all of the tools they offer including managing that list. They also handle spam law compliance issues and you don't have to worry about your server being blacklisted for sending spam.

Answer (score 1):

You will never be able to add 40k email addresses to the BCC line of an email client. The developers purposes restrict size on this field to assist with spam control.

The best solution I have used and seen used on many big sites is [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/).

You could try breaking up the list of users into groups and send. Breakup or categorize alphabetically, or by groups of user types etc. This way you will be able to target and receive valuable info back on your user sets.